# Grav CMS form Integraion with Recaptcha v3

Tags: forms, recaptcha, grav, recaptcha-v3

I am using Grav form  v2.16.4 - i want to integrate recaptcha v3 to it but it doesn't work.

I have added the below field to it as in the documentation, please let me know if there is any issue in it?

```html
 recaptcha:
 name: g-recaptcha-response
 version: 2-checkbox
 site_key: 6LczAsUUAAAefefwefwefe
 secret_key: sfefefwefwfcaEB0fsadzKggE
 type: hidden
```

Here is the documentation i followed -(https://learn.getgrav.org/16/forms/forms/fields-available#captcha-field), 
And also i have added the recaptcha script in the head , which shows the recaptch symbol on the site now.

please help on this. i m not familiar with Grav cms.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi - i have found an solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Here is the solution - so what i did was - i updated the Grav form to version 4, then there you could find the recaptch latest version 3 in the drop down. And after that just need to put this code to the form -

```html
 -        
           name: g-recaptcha-response
           label: Captcha
           type: captcha
           recaptcha_site_key: ////////
           recaptcha_not_validated: 'Captcha not valid!'
           validate:
                required: true
```

And In process

```html
process:
        -
           captcha:
                recaptcha_secret: ///////
        -
            save:
                fileprefix: feedback-
                dateformat: Ymd-His-u
                extension: txt
```

This worked for me, please let me know if anyone need help on this.